# Error while disabling publishing and distribution

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

Hi I delete all publications and subscriptions on sql server 2008 . Then try to disabling publishing and distribution for reconfigure replication but have an error :

**An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
Invalid object name 'dbo.sysmergesubscriptions'.
Changed database context to 'master'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 208)** Ho solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is: create that object by yourself. Most likely there would be more than one table/view missing. Just script those missing objects from another database (for example, develop environment) and create them in your production box.